# update some rows in code igniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

i'm new to codeigniter.
i need some help to update some rows.

**here is my model:**

```
public function change()
{
    $aa = $this->input->post('id');
    $bb = $this->input->post('app');

    $query = $this->db->query('select kodeunit from user where email = "hehe@gmail.com"');
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $kode = $row->kodeunit;
        }

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($aa);$i++)
    {
        $data = array(
                    'approval' => $bb[$i]
        );
        $this->db->where('id_team', $aa[$i]);
        $this->db->where('kodeunit', $kode);
        $this->db->update('detail_tim', $data);
    }
}
```

when i tried to update only one row, it worked with this way. but when im trying to update some rows, it doesnt change at all. 
please help me to fix this problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `sizeof()` in your for loop, instead use $aa directly if it's an integer or `count($aa)` if it's an array

```
for($i=0;$i<count($aa);$i++)
```

it'll be better if you make it to other variable

```
$max = count($aa);
for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++)
```

Comment: Is it have some effects to my update query @budirec ?

Comment: Oh, my bad, apparently `sizeof()` is just an alias for `count()` in php.
can you give a data sample as I see nothing wrong in the code so far

Comment: Yep hehehe. Nothing wrong, there is no error message too in my codeigniter, but it doesnt update anything and idk why @budirec

Comment: Also a var_dump of $aa and $bb will be great. or do profiling of your code by turning on
    `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);`

Comment: I dont really understand. Can u please re write my code that'll change. Thanks before :) @budirec

Comment: Well, your code might be ok, the problem is what's inside $aa and $bb, can you do var_dump on those?
`var_dump($aa);echo'<br>';var_dump($bb);` 
when you tried updating more than 1 row

Comment: Okay i'll try it first. Thankyou for helping @budirec :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103138/discussion-between-budirec-and-juliana-sucahya).